# deeply nested content_tag, concat and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, helper

I'm frustrated using Rails 3.2 and making a helper for Bootstrap modals.  I don't understand when you need concat versus when you don't sometimes I end up with tags missing and sometimes I end up with a hash with all the options between before and ending tags.  When I use concat on any content-tag with a do-end all hell breaks loose.  All I want to do is replicate this html:

```
<div id="stupid_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fontello-icon-cancel-1"></i></button>
        <h4>Modal header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="page-header">
            <p>Test header 1 2 3.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">

           content here... blah blah

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-green">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot for the life of me get the button in the h4 in the modal header to work out right.  Neither can I get the page header to appear in the modal body.

My helper looks like this:

```
module ModalHelper
def modal(css_id, header_text, hidden = true, options = {},&block)
    class_text = "modal"
    class_text += " hide fade" if hidden
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'modal hide fade', :id => css_id, :style => ("display:none;" if hidden)) do 
        concat modal_header(header_text)
        concat modal_body(&block)
        concat modal_footer
    end
end

def modal_button(link_text, href)
    modal_caller link_text, href, :button
end

def modal_link(link_text, href)
    modal_caller link_text, href
end

private

def modal_caller(link_text, href, type = nil)
    options = { :"data-toggle" => "modal" }
    options.merge!({ :class => "btn" }) if type == :button
    link_to link_text, "#" + href, options
end

def modal_header(header_text)
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'modal-header') do
        concat content_tag(:button,(content_tag(:i, :class => 'fontello-icon-cancel-1')),:class => 'close', :"data-dismiss" => 'modal', :"aria-hidden" => 'true')
        concat content_tag(:h4, header_text)
    end
end

def modal_body(page_header = "")
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'modal-body') do
        content_tag(:div, :class => 'page-header') do
            concat content_tag(:p, page_header)
        end
        content_tag(:div, :class => 'row-fluid') do
            yield
        end
    end     
end 

def modal_footer
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'modal-footer') do
        concat content_tag(:button, 'Close', type: "button", :class => 'btn btn-boo', :"data-dismiss" => 'modal')
        concat content_tag(:button, 'Save', type: "button", class: 'btn btn-green')
    end     
end
```

end

And the link looks like this:

```
<%= modal_link "New Stupid Modal", "stupid_modal" %>
```

And the modal html looks like this:

```
<%= modal('stupid_modal', 'Shouldnt this work?', submit: true, tabindex: '-1') do %>
    <% render 'stupid_modal_partials/stupid_modal' %>
<% end %>
```

The output is this:

```
<button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i>{:class=&gt;&quot;fontello-icon-cancel-1&quot;}</i></button>
```

which looks like this in the page source:

```
<i>{:class=>"fontello-icon-cancel-1"}</i>
```

**Update:**

changing modal_header to this works:

```
def modal_header(header_text)
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'modal-header') do
        concat content_tag(:button,(content_tag(:i, "",:class => 'fontello-icon-cancel-1')),:class => 'close', :"data-dismiss" => 'modal', :"aria-hidden" => 'true')
        concat content_tag(:h4, header_text)
    end
end
```

But this doesn't:

```
def modal_header(header_text)
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'modal-header') do
        concat content_tag(:button,:class => 'close', :"data-dismiss" => 'modal', :"aria-hidden" => 'true') do
            concat content_tag(:i, "",:class => 'fontello-icon-cancel-1')
        end
        concat content_tag(:h4, header_text)
    end
end
```

which begs the question, wzup with concat? and am i missing something -- I also tried empty quotes as the second argument to the button content_tag

Comment: And I've tried the i tag inside the button tag's content_tag do-end instead of inline.  no love.

Comment: This article explains the user of `concat` and `capture` well: http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to ever use `concat`.

Each Rails helper returns a string with some html in it:

```
tag(:br) # "<br>"
```

So your simplest helper method would be this:

```
# "<br>"
def br
  tag(:br)
end
```

If you have multiple strings of html just sum them up:

```
# "<button>Close</button><button>Save</button>"
def modal_buttons
  content_tag(:button, "Close") + content_tag(:button, "Save")
end
```

Note that you can't just call them as they don't modify the view

```
# "<button>Save</button>"
def modal_buttons
  content_tag(:button, "Close") # this won't do anything
  content_tag(:button, "Save")
end
```

For blocks the same rules apply:

```
# "<div><button>Close</button><button>Save</button></div>"
def modal_footer
  content_tag(:div) do
    # what block returns will be inside the div
    content_tag(:button, "Close") + content_tag(:button, "Save")
  end
end

def modal_body
  content_tag(:div) do
    modal_header + yield + modal_footer
  end
end
```

As a side note, using just Rails helpers to construct the whole view isn't really their intended purpose. They are supposed to *help* you in dynamic places, static html is better done in ERB templates.

Comment: This is helpful.  Will try. I figured a helper for modals and using partials for the main body is a good way to clean up my views.